# Extract statistics from google play

Tags: java, google-play

I'm building some statistics and would like to have the statistics from google play (the app store) as well. Information like most popular, downloads, price, etc.

Does anyone know if there is an API for this or do I have to scrape it myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a project called android-market-api http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api. Start from there.

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/source/browse/trunk/AndroidMarketApi/proto/market.proto. Look at App definition there to get idea of what you could extract.

You can ask the guy who wrote it how he reverse-engineered the protocol of Android market.

Using it you can make searches and then get info per application.