# Google play search api or partner feed?

Tags: api

Does anyone know if there is a search api for google play. I'm particularly interested in searching for apps.

iTunes has a great search api and also an enterprise partner feed containing all the information. Does google offer the same?

Comment: @Halley How can it be a copy (the link is to this page)

Comment: I am sorry that I post the incorrect link, and I removed my previous comment. Actually there are a lot of posts about this already. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10272155/1241690 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/1308346/1241690 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/6469200/1241690 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/4557300/1241690 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/10868037/1241690 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)

> **An open-source API for the Android Market**
>
> This is not an official api. I'm not afiliated to google in any way.
>
> This library allow you to ask directly google's official android market servers for information, search for apps, ...

**Note:**
Google Rebranded Android Market, Google Music as 'Play' on March 6, 2012.